# How to fix "cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object" error in django admin whilst using custom user model

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use a custom user model and I am working with the `AbstractBaseUser` class. However, when I try to create a new user from the admin end, I get this error:

> "cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object"

I am able to view users from the admin end, but when I try to add a new user, I get this error.

My custom user model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
        """docstring for Users"""
        status = (
        ('1', 'Verified'),
        ('0', 'Unverified'),
    )

        username = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=200,unique=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
        password = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
        phone = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
        country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        state = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
        age  = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True)
        verified = models.CharField(max_length=1, default=0)
        verification_code = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        pass_code = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
        avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_user_image,default=None, max_length=1024)
        bio = models.TextField(max_length=1024,default=None)
        registration_date = models.DateTimeField()
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255,unique=True)

        objects = MyUserManager()

        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'username','phone','country','state','city','address','age','registration_date']

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
                self.slug = slugify(self.name)
                super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        def __str__(self):
                return self.name
        def get_full_name(self):
                return self.name

        def get_short_name(self):
                return self.name

        def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
            #"Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
                    return True

        def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        #"Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
                return True

        @property
        def is_staff(self):
        #"Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
                return self.is_admin

        def get_username(self):
         return super().get_username()

        def set_password(self, raw_password):
         return super().set_password(raw_password)

        def check_password(self, raw_password):
         return super().check_password(raw_password)

        def normalize_username(cls, username):
         return super().normalize_username(username)
```

My custom usermanager:

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self,username, name, email,phone,country,state,city,address,age,registration_date,verification_code=None,password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        user = self.model(
                        username = self.normalize_username(username),
                        name = name,
                        email = self.normalize_email(email),
                        phone = phone,
                        country = country,
                        state = state,
                        city = city,
                        address = address,
                        age = age,
                        verification_code = self.make_random_password(),
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self,username, name, email,phone,country,state,city,address,age,registration_date, password):
        user = self.create_user(username, name, email,phone,country,state,city,address,age,registration_date, password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_active = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

My admin.py :

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField 
from liber.models import User


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label = 'Password',widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label = 'Password Confirmation',widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name','username', 'email','phone','country','state','city','address','age','registration_date')


    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.clean_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.clean_data.get('password2')

        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords Do Not Match')
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.clean_data['password1'])
        user.verification_code = User.objects.make_random_password()
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name','username', 'email','password','phone','country','state','city','address','age','registration_date','is_active','is_admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        return self.initial['password']

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    """docstring for UsersAdmin"""
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("name",)}

    list_display = ('name','username', 'email','phone','country','state','city','address','age','registration_date','is_active','is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields':('username','email','password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('name','phone','country','state','city','address','age','registration_date',)}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields':('is_admin',)}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
                'classes':('wide',),
                'fields':('name','username', 'email','phone','country','state','city','address','age','registration_date','password1','password2')
            }
        )
    )
    search_fields = ('username','email')
    ordering = ('username','email')
    filter_horizontal = ()

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

The full traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/liber/user/add/

Django Version: 2.2
Python Version: 3.7.1
Installed Applications:
['liber.apps.LiberConfig',
 'dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Success\Envs\libre\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Success\Envs\libre\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Success\Envs\libre\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Success\Envs\libre\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  606.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Success\Envs\libre\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Success\Envs\libre\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Success\Envs\libre\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Success\Envs\libre\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Success\Envs\libre\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Success\Envs\libre\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Success\Envs\libre\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Success\Envs\libre\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\admin.py" in add_view
  99.             return self._add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)

File "C:\Users\Success\Envs\libre\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\admin.py" in _add_view
  126.         return super().add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)

File "C:\Users\Success\Envs\libre\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in add_view
  1634.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)

File "C:\Users\Success\Envs\libre\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Success\Envs\libre\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Success\Envs\libre\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changeform_view
  1522.             return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "C:\Users\Success\Envs\libre\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in _changeform_view
  1551.         ModelForm = self.get_form(request, obj, change=not add)

File "C:\Users\Success\Envs\libre\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\admin.py" in get_form
  80.         return super().get_form(request, obj, **defaults)

File "C:\Users\Success\Envs\libre\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in get_form
  669.             fields = flatten_fieldsets(self.get_fieldsets(request, obj))

File "C:\Users\Success\Envs\libre\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\utils.py" in flatten_fieldsets
  96.     for name, opts in fieldsets:

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/liber/user/add/
Exception Value: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Comment: `Meta`,  not `meta`

Comment: thanks for the observation. I've corrected it, but the error is still showing. Meanwhile, I am able to edit existing user

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `add_fieldsets` isn't defined as a tuple/list itself, it's just `()` around another tuple. So your code just sees `(None, {})` as the tuple, whereas it's expecting a tuple of tuples.

You need to either use square brackets or add a `,` after the only element of your list:

```
add_fieldsets = (
    (None, {
            'classes':('wide',),
            'fields':('name','username', 'email','phone','country','state','city','address','age','registration_date','password1','password2')
        }
    ),  # <-- add this comma!
)
```

or

```
add_fieldsets = [
    (None, {
            'classes':('wide',),
            'fields':('name','username', 'email','phone','country','state','city','address','age','registration_date','password1','password2')
        }
    )
]  # <-- list
```